# Access the last element of a nested database

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]How to get the last element in a nested database in firebase.
This is my db

In this there are several ids and for each id under the bot's msg i want the last message which in this case will be

```
I am fine.Thank You....
```

I know the brute approach but it will take a lot of time.

Here is my code :

```
    return ref.child(user).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    var i = 0;
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
        console.log(snap.child('bot').child('msg').msg);
        snap.child('bot').child('msg')
        .forEach((openTicketSnapshot) => {
            var val = openTicketSnapshot.val();
            val.forEach((text) => {
                 userMsg2.push({
                     'who': 'User',
                     'msg': text.msg,
                     'time': text.timestamp
                 });

            })

        });

      //Here i will access the last index of userMsg




    var data1 = {
        "data": "found"
    };
    res.json(data1);
    // ...
    return data1;
})
```

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: you can use limitToLast in that reference

Comment: But i want all the id and for each id i want the bot's last message

Comment: what does this `console.log(snap.child('bot').child('msg').msg);` give you?

Comment: undefined value

Comment: yes I thought so.., `console.log(snapshot)` should contain all data inside `user` and contain all the `ids` you can then do `snap.child('bot').child('msg').limitToLast(1)
        .forEach((openTicketSnapshot) => {` to get the last one

Comment: getting error saying limitToLast is not a function